# What stock UIKit classes are Focusable?

Tags: uikit, focus, tvos

Out of the various stock UIKit classes, which ones are considered focusable by default by the Focus Engine on tvOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [David House](https://www.bignerdranch.com/about/the-team/david-house/) on [Big Nerd Ranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/10-tips-for-mastering-the-focus-engine-on-tvos/), the following UIKit classes are focusable:

- UIButton
- UITextField
- UITableView
- UICollectionView
- UITextView
- UISegmentedControl
- UISearchBar

Note that this is different from which classes conform to the UIFocusEnvironment protocol; the above are what would return `true` on `canBecomeFocused`

Comment: Also good to know is that above mentioned objects won't be focusable when user interaction is disabled, or when the view's alpha value is equal to `0`.